# Corona SDK Scrollview: double scrollview structure with linked contents

Tags: lua, widget, scrollview, coronasdk

I need to do a structure of scrollview like that:

[image]

I need a principal scrollview (A) that can scroll only in vertical, and a linked scrollview ( B) that can scoll in horizontal.

The contents that are in the yellow are should be moved in vertical if i scroll the A scrollview and in horizontal too with the B one.

i try to do like that:

```
    local scrollView =  widget.newScrollView
    {
        top = display.contentHeight* 0.08,
        left = 0,
        width = display.contentWidth,
        height = display.contentHeight * 0.85,
        scrollWidth = scrollWidthGlobal,
        scrollHeight = scrollHeightGlobal,
        hideBackground = true,
        listener = scrollListener,
        topPadding = - 25,
        bottomPadding = 0,
        horizontalScrollDisabled = true
    }

----- SOME CONTENT ------

local OscrollView =  widget.newScrollView
        {
            top = 0,
            left = L6X,
            width = display.contentWidth - L6X,
            height = display.contentHeight * 0.925,
            -- scrollWidth = display.contentWidth,
            -- scrollHeight = display.contentHeight * 0.85,
            hideBackground = true,
            listener = scrollListener2,
            leftPadding = 0, 
            rightPadding = 0,
            horizontalScrollDisabled = false,
            verticalScrollDisabled = true
        }

local try1 = display.newText("X")
try1.x, try1.y = positionX, positionY

scrollView:insert( OTHERCONTENTS )
scrollView:insert( try1 )

OscrollView:insert( try1 )
```

If I left like that, the object try1 scroll only with the second scrollview (in horizontal). If I don't insert the object in one of two scrollview, as normal, not scroll with the one it not insert.

I tryed too insert the second scrollview in the first one too, but with no effect.

Some one can help me? It is possible to do a structure like that with corona?

Excuse me for my bad english,
Hope you'll help me.
Roberto

Comment: I'm not sure I understand exactly, but you basically want two scrollviews, one inside the other?

Comment: Yes more or less like in the draw. The problem is that in the yellow zone i can't scroll dates in each side.

Comment: I'm taking somewhat of a wild guess here, but I think the events are getting blocked by one of the scrollviews. What I mean by this, is that when one of the scrolls gets a touch event, it doesn't propagate it to the other scroll if they're overlapping.

Comment: Yes that it is, the fact is that probably there is no way to make it if not to pass objects that are in yellow zone between the two scrollview each time i move one of them... but this you have to aplicate to every single object its present in that zone and is really long (as I have really much datas). 

My question is if is possible (and how to do it if yes) to make it more easy.

Comment: I think this is wrong approach. Can you explain why you can't use one scroll view with both scroll bars active to achieve the same effect?

Comment: It's because only the yellow zone should scroll in each direction. The other parts or only in vertical (for A scrollview), or only in horizontal (for B one). Now I'm trying one approach. If is good I'll post the solution